# Why system pallet compiled failed caused by benchamrking part

Tags: substrate-node-template

just now, I modify the deps in cargo.toml, degrade from master to polkadot-v0.9.17 branch the compiler throw an error about this

```
     Compiling sp-consensus-aura v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
 Compiling pallet-session v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
 Compiling frame-system-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
 Compiling pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
 Compiling pallet-aura v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
```

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `set_block_number` found for struct `frame_system::Pallet` in the current scope
--> /home/george/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/frame/system/benchmarking/src/lib.rs:35:1
|
35  | / benchmarks! {
36  | |     remark {
37  | |         let b in 0 .. *T::BlockLength::get().max.get(DispatchClass::Normal) as u32;
38  | |         let remark_message = vec![1; b as usize];
...   |
127 | |     impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, crate::mock::new_test_ext(), crate::mock::Test);
128 | | }
| | ^
| | |
| |_function or associated item not found in `frame_system::Pallet<T>`
|   help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `block_number`
|
= note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_benchmark` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Comment: Please only open *either* an issue in Substrate or ask here, not both. Thanks.